# Laravel setting up circle CI

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, circleci

I want to setup circle Ci, here's my full config file:

```
version: 2
 jobs:
     build:
         steps:
            - run: sudo apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev
            - run: composer install -n --ignore-platform-reqs
            - run: npm install
            - run: npm run production
            - run: vendor/bin/phpunit

            - run:
               name: Start Chrome Driver
               command: ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux
               background: true

            - run:
               name: Run Laravel Server
               command: php artisan serve
               background: true

            - run:
               name: Run Laravel Dusk Tests
               command: php artisan dusk
```

however I get this error message:

> build-agent version 0.0.4142-1bd195a (2017-09-11T09:57:00+0000)
>   Configuration errors: 2 errors occurred:
>
> - Error parsing config file: yaml: line 1: mapping values are not allowed in this context
> - Cannot find a job named `build` to run in the `jobs:` section of your configuration file. This can happen if you have no workflows
>     defined, or a typo in your 'workflows:' config.

I use AWS RDS database for my production, is it possible that during the testing it uses different database, i.e local? fake some information and then purge the database after the test? This must not affect  my production database. Also the issue I have need to be fixed but I don't know what's wrong here

Comment: Can you try to get rid of any spaces before `jobs:`?

This should be on the same level as `version:`.

Answer (score 0):

This one might be helpful

[config.yml](https://gist.github.com/sam0hack/acf79ef4a9b73bb7c42d2579153e5ba4)